# Overloading C++ subscript [] operator with long int index possible?

Tags: c++

In every example I only see `int` as the argument for indexing the array:

```
unsigned char& operator[](int i)
{
...
}
```

I wonder if this is possible?:

```
unsigned char& operator[](__int64 i)
{
...
}
```

I would like to create an array like class, where I could access the entire address space of a given process as an array, which can be larger then 4GB (32bit) on a 64 bit OS.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I dont have the actual implementation ready yet to try. But I was thinking if its not possible, why would I bother coding it if at the end I'd have to throw it out.

Comment: I guess to learn something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use any type you want, although `__int64` may not be the most portable choice. Try `std::int64_t` or `std::uint64_t` instead (or `size_t`/`ptrdiff_t`).

If you want examples with different types than `int` look no further than [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) and [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is gaining popularity these days too.